# Postgres SQL. Table normalization, I can’t remove duplicates

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm currently working with a CSV-formatted table that has incomplete data scattered across various columns. The missing data is inconsistent, appearing in different columns at different times. Consequently, it's challenging to group the data by a unique column, leading to significant data loss.

I'm facing difficulty communicating with ChatGPT, and the suggestions provided so far haven't proven helpful in resolving my issue. I'm feeling quite desperate at the moment. Any assistance you could offer would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

| staff_id | staff_age | staff_first_name | staff_last_name | staff_lang |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18-31/55 | 43 | Marcellus | Lucas | NULL |
| 18-31/55 | 43 | NULL | NULL | Guaraní |
| 18-31/55 | NULL | Marcellus | Lucas | Guaraní |
| 22-98/02 | 58 | Franklin | Paul | NULL |
| 22-98/02 | 58 | NULL | NULL | Filipino |
| 22-98/02 | NULL | Franklin | Paul | Filipino |
| 24-21/43 | 36 | Mitchel | Newman | NULL |
| 24-21/43 | 36 | NULL | NULL | Luxembourgish |
| 24-21/43 | NULL | Mitchel | Newman | Luxembourgish |
| 24-62/82 | 17 | Hobert | Mckenzie | NULL |
| 24-62/82 | 17 | NULL | NULL | Tamil |
| 24-62/82 | NULL | Hobert | Mckenzie | Tamil |
| 33-45/91 | 58 | Malcom | Cunningham | NULL |
| 33-45/91 | 58 | NULL | NULL | Belarusian |
| 33-45/91 | NULL | Malcom | Cunningham | Belarusian |
| 34-35/30 | 37 | Louvenia | Black | NULL |
| 34-35/30 | 37 | NULL | NULL | Nepali |
| 34-35/30 | NULL | Louvenia | Black | Nepali |
| 49-13/30 | 43 | Charita | Chavez | NULL |
| 49-13/30 | 43 | NULL | NULL | Gagauz |
| 49-13/30 | NULL | Charita | Chavez | Gagauz |
| 83-99/74 | 45 | Myron | Ewing | NULL |
| 83-99/74 | 45 | NULL | NULL | English |
| 83-99/74 | NULL | Myron | Ewing | English |
| 84-14/62 | 24 | Millard | Leon | NULL |
| 84-14/62 | 24 | NULL | NULL | Fijian |
| 84-14/62 | NULL | Millard | Leon | Fijian |
| 91-35/32 | 55 | Cornelius | Goodwin | NULL |
| 91-35/32 | 55 | NULL | NULL | Czech |
| 91-35/32 | NULL | Cornelius | Goodwin | Czech |
| NULL | 17 | Hobert | Mckenzie | Tamil |
| NULL | 24 | Millard | Leon | Fijian |
| NULL | 36 | Mitchel | Newman | Luxembourgish |
| NULL | 37 | Louvenia | Black | Nepali |
| NULL | 43 | Charita | Chavez | Gagauz |
| NULL | 43 | Marcellus | Lucas | Guaraní |
| NULL | 45 | Myron | Ewing | English |
| NULL | 55 | Cornelius | Goodwin | Czech |
| NULL | 58 | Franklin | Paul | Filipino |
| NULL | 58 | Malcom | Cunningham | Belarusian |

There was an idea to join the table on itself, but it only got worse.

```
select distinct

COALESCE(t1.staff_id, t2.staff_id) AS staff_id,
  
COALESCE(t1.staff_age, t2.staff_age) AS staff_age,
  
COALESCE(t1.staff_first_name, t2.staff_first_name) AS staff_first_name,
  
COALESCE(t1.staff_last_name, t2.staff_last_name) AS staff_last_name,
  
COALESCE(t1.staff_lang, t2.staff_lang) AS staff_lang

from corrected_orders_data_staff t1
join corrected_orders_data_staff t2 on
(
(t1.staff_id = t2.staff_id and t1.staff_age = t2.staff_age) or
(t1.staff_id = t2.staff_id and t1.staff_first_name = t2.staff_first_name and t1.staff_last_name = t2.staff_last_name) or
(t1.staff_id = t2.staff_id and t1.staff_lang = t2.staff_lang) or
(t1.staff_age = t2.staff_age and t1.staff_first_name = t2.staff_first_name and t1.staff_last_name = t2.staff_last_name) or
(t1.staff_age = t2.staff_age and t1.staff_lang = t2.staff_lang) or
(t1.staff_first_name = t2.staff_first_name and t1.staff_last_name = t2.staff_last_name and t1.staff_lang = t2.staff_lang) --or
)
order by 1,2,3,4,5
;
```

Comment: As long as you are using ChatGPT, it's actually very handy for converting csv data to markdown tables. ex: "Turn this list into a Stack Overflow markdown formatted table:"

Comment: Can you provide your desired result from this sample? It's difficult to infer what exactly clean means to you just from a sample of dirty data.

Comment: For example, for rows with the value Marcellus, the table displays 4 rows. I would like only one. Previously, for such problems, I used grouping, but here I can’t do it due to the partial lack of data in each of the columns.
For example, from the tablet

|1|null|3|4|

|null|2|null|4|

|null|6|null|8|
|null|6|7|null|

I would like to display the data in the form

|1|2|3|4|

|null|6|7|8|


but preferably sql query

Comment: "... I can't remove duplicates" -- What is a duplicate for you?

Comment: @DinoMino I know it's tedious, but you'll get much better answers if you provide an exact corresponding result table to your sample data. Since the data is unclean it's tough  to guess all the rules you want applied. Specifically, my answer assumes the staff_id can always take precedence when it's not null. And that records with a null value for staff_id won't contain any novel data. If this isn't the case, a sample and result that shows that handling explicitly would help a great deal.

Answer (score 1):

How important are those records with NULL for staff id? Just from this sample it looks like all of their data is captured piecewise by a record with a non-null staff id.

```
CREATE TABLE some_test_data (
    staff_id VARCHAR(20),
    staff_age INTEGER,
    staff_first_name VARCHAR(50),
    staff_last_name VARCHAR(50),
    staff_lang VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO some_test_data (staff_id, staff_age, staff_first_name, staff_last_name, staff_lang)
VALUES 
('18-31/55', 43, 'Marcellus', 'Lucas', NULL),
('18-31/55', 43, NULL, NULL, 'Guaraní'),
('18-31/55', NULL, 'Marcellus', 'Lucas', 'Guaraní'),
('22-98/02', 58, 'Franklin', 'Paul', NULL),
('22-98/02', 58, NULL, NULL, 'Filipino'),
('22-98/02', NULL, 'Franklin', 'Paul', 'Filipino'),
('24-21/43', 36, 'Mitchel', 'Newman', NULL),
('24-21/43', 36, NULL, NULL, 'Luxembourgish'),
('24-21/43', NULL, 'Mitchel', 'Newman', 'Luxembourgish'),
('24-62/82', 17, 'Hobert', 'Mckenzie', NULL),
('24-62/82', 17, NULL, NULL, 'Tamil'),
('24-62/82', NULL, 'Hobert', 'Mckenzie', 'Tamil'),
('33-45/91', 58, 'Malcom', 'Cunningham', NULL),
('33-45/91', 58, NULL, NULL, 'Belarusian'),
('33-45/91', NULL, 'Malcom', 'Cunningham', 'Belarusian'),
('34-35/30', 37, 'Louvenia', 'Black', NULL),
('34-35/30', 37, NULL, NULL, 'Nepali'),
('34-35/30', NULL, 'Louvenia', 'Black', 'Nepali'),
('49-13/30', 43, 'Charita', 'Chavez', NULL),
('49-13/30', 43, NULL, NULL, 'Gagauz'),
('49-13/30', NULL, 'Charita', 'Chavez', 'Gagauz'),
('83-99/74', 45, 'Myron', 'Ewing', NULL),
('83-99/74', 45, NULL, NULL, 'English'),
('83-99/74', NULL, 'Myron', 'Ewing', 'English'),
('84-14/62', 24, 'Millard', 'Leon', NULL),
('84-14/62', 24, NULL, NULL, 'Fijian'),
('84-14/62', NULL, 'Millard', 'Leon', 'Fijian'),
('91-35/32', 55, 'Cornelius', 'Goodwin', NULL),
('91-35/32', 55, NULL, NULL, 'Czech'),
('91-35/32', NULL, 'Cornelius', 'Goodwin', 'Czech'),
(NULL, 17, 'Hobert', 'Mckenzie', 'Tamil'),
(NULL, 24, 'Millard', 'Leon', 'Fijian'),
(NULL, 36, 'Mitchel', 'Newman', 'Luxembourgish'),
(NULL, 37, 'Louvenia', 'Black', 'Nepali'),
(NULL, 43, 'Charita', 'Chavez', 'Gagauz'),
(NULL, 43, 'Marcellus', 'Lucas', 'Guaraní'),
(NULL, 45, 'Myron', 'Ewing', 'English'),
(NULL, 55, 'Cornelius', 'Goodwin', 'Czech'),
(NULL, 58, 'Franklin', 'Paul', 'Filipino'),
(NULL, 58, 'Malcom', 'Cunningham', 'Belarusian');


with infer_null_attributes_by_staff_id as 
(
    select staff_id,
           max(staff_age) as staff_age,
           max(staff_first_name) as staff_first_name,
           max(staff_last_name) as staff_last_name,
           max(staff_lang) as staff_lang
      from some_test_data
     where staff_id is not null
     group
        by staff_id
)
select * 
  from infer_null_attributes_by_staff_id;
```

| staff_id | staff_age | staff_first_name | staff_last_name | staff_lang |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 49-13/30 | 43 | Charita | Chavez | Gagauz |
| 24-21/43 | 36 | Mitchel | Newman | Luxembourgish |
| 84-14/62 | 24 | Millard | Leon | Fijian |
| 83-99/74 | 45 | Myron | Ewing | English |
| 34-35/30 | 37 | Louvenia | Black | Nepali |
| 33-45/91 | 58 | Malcom | Cunningham | Belarusian |
| 18-31/55 | 43 | Marcellus | Lucas | Guaraní |
| 91-35/32 | 55 | Cornelius | Goodwin | Czech |
| 24-62/82 | 17 | Hobert | Mckenzie | Tamil |
| 22-98/02 | 58 | Franklin | Paul | Filipino |